# EF Core. Удаление зависимой записи

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Всем привет. Имееются 2 таблицы. Товар - Категория. Связаны через внешний ключ.
Теперь суть задачи. Как вы поняли, по категории можно определить, какие товары к ней относятся. Но! Есть проблема. Нужна возможность удалять товары. Но при удалении, выдает исключение, что объект привязан к другому объекту. Из-за чего удалить не удается.

Многим придет в голову каскадное удаление. Но, как я понимаю, при каскадном удалении, удаляются все зависимые записи. А мне нужно только одну.

То есть, удалить товар, но категория при этом остается.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: какая связь? 1 товар - много категорий?

Comment: Один ко многим. Одна категория, много товаров.

Comment: Значит что-то не правильно. Скорее всего товар "привязан" не к категории, а к чему-то другому.

Comment: Забыл сказать. Он привязан к 3 объектам. Там также есть подкатегории.

Comment: покажите схему таблиц и ваши модели

Comment: нет моделей - вопрос ни о чём и его нужно закрыть, проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: Ну вообще-то этот вопрос уже давно был решен. Я просто забыл оветить. Дело в том, что при отправке запроса я не указывал id.